# Reading a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read a name and print it. But the control doesn't wait for me to enter the name and directly prints the output with some meaningless characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Any mistakes here?

Comment: Namespace std is not C, it's C++.

Comment: This is not C, `using namespace` is C++. Remove that, and make sure you build as C.

Comment: How have you managed to compile the code when you say the program doesn't wait for input and prints meaningless characters?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler just ignore `using namespace std;` because it's never actually referenced?

Comment: Your code compiles and works fine with a C++ compiler. If you want it to compile with a C compiler you need to remove the `using namespace std;` line, then it will also compile and work. So please tell us a bit more of what exactly you are doing, which OS you have, which compiler, version, IDE, what youb type where etc.

Comment: what can happen here is: 1) the code doesn't compile 2) you're running an old, unrelated executable with the same name.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Just trying out online https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: 1)It compiled fine and 2)Just trying out online codechef.com/ide

Comment: why using online platforms to test your code? what's wrong with local installations?

Comment: Please refrain from stating `I am new to X and Y`...that is having no context with the question being asked.

Comment: On codechef, have you selected the custom input? It works fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/XTJy1s)...

Comment: @Bob__ : Thanks.. This is want i had missed.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre :Will prefer it next time.

Answer (score 5):

In C this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

doesn't exist.

Here is your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%19s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Hint: assuming that your buffer is 20, use `scanf("%19s", name);` to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: Now the next question probably would be "How can I make `scanf()` to accept spaces?"

Comment: Nope.Checked after removing namespace.

Comment: Have you already tryed with scanf(" %19s", name); instead of scanf("%19s", name); ? Maybe you have to consume the newline character.

Comment: `in C there isn't namespace`.... ___my whole life is a lie then___ , care to elaborate the chapter 6.2.3, `C11`?

Comment: I mean namespace as 'using namespace std;' not namespace as struct etc

Comment: @Overflow404 So, care to change the statement to avoid confusion? ..probably add `keyword`....just a suggestion.